Electron Forge + ESM
I've been trying to make a project created via Electron Forge to work with ESM.
At this point, ESM is mostly a must, since required libraries are exporting only to ESM and using older libraries is not accepted. Also, I'd like to avoid hacks, forks, and weird imports (i.e. import-sync) to make them work in CommonJS.
So the current state is supposed to be that Electron supports ESM since v28.
Forge is a tool for packaging acquire from Electron (repo is in electron/forge) but the forge.config.ts file doesn't seem to like ESM imports...
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: ~\forge.config.ts
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of ~\forge.config.ts from ~\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\dist\util\forge-config.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from ~\package.json.

tsconfig.json configured like this (+ type: "module"),
"module": "node16",
"moduleResolution": "node16",
"moduleDetection": "force",

seems to make everything work... but can't start the Forge app.
on the other hand, having it like
"module": "commonjs"
"moduleResolution": "node",

it starts the Forge app, everything looks ok, it's even able to import some ESM packages such as nanoid... but with others like electron-store the types are not recognized properly (like this problem)
So I guess the question is...
What's the current state of Electron development? Are we in a world were nothing can be set to work perfectly anymore? Or am I missing some step here? I feel like I've tried most possible configurations...

Have you tried to rename the config file to .cjs?

@Arkellys Haven't thought about that! Renamed it to .cts now!

well... having it as a .cts / .cjs requires to have async.dynamic imports which are not allowed on the top level and the configuration for Forge doesn't allow async functions afaik... so probably it's not supported because of that...

Maybe juste try to use export default instead of module.export then? I remember someone who had trouble with Forge and ESM and asked for help on Electron's Discord, they said this helped them.

ever figure out a solution?

@Spankied no. So I did what any frontend engineer would do: created a whole new boilerplate repo for electron+tsx: https://github.com/danikaze/electron-tsx-app (still getting improved with a few mods such an electron-ipc-logger: https://github.com/danikaze/electron-ipc-logger and other improvements...)
